# how to create range of integer values as vector or array in C++ / C?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, matlab, testing

I came from world of matlab and Python, recently Im learning C/C++ languages .
Im trying to find best approach to create range of integers in C/C++ that starts from number 1 till the other determined limit.

In MATLAB I was just doing this:
`x = 1:10`, then I get that `x` is a matrix of `1x10` (an array which equals to `x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`;
`x = 1:5`, then I get that `x` is a matrix of `1x10` (an array which equals to `x = [1 2 3 4 5 ]`;

So how do I implement that in C++ or C ? I want to create a range -I define its limits- in simple approach and in the best way and store its values as array/list/vector as what I showed above in matlab.

THANKS !

Comment: Wouldn't a loop be the simplest way to do that?

Comment: No "C or C++ questions" please. You've got to pick **one** programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `std::iota` for this purpose.

Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

in C++20 you can use that as range factory.

Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view)

There is not more to explain . . .